# Alarmmanager working sometimes on device

Tags: android, alarmmanager

The alarmmanager is working perfectly on emulator but not on physical device.
It works sometimes on the device. Please help. i cant find why its not working on device. Is there a bug?
The same code was working fine earlier.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.wim.wimonandroid"
android:versionCode="94"
android:versionName="10.1" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:name=".wimOnAndroid"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Compas"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TutorialZoomActivity1"
        android:label="@string/ramadan" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AlarmListView"
        android:label="@string/app_name3" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".wimRss"
        android:label="@string/app_name1" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CityListView"
        android:label="@string/app_name4" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".jummah"
        android:label="@string/jummah" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".settings"
        android:label="@string/settings" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".QA"
        android:label="@string/QA" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SendEmailActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name_Sendmail" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Touch"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".compass"
        android:label="@string/compass" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:name=".sehri"
        android:label="sehri" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:name=".iftari"
        android:label="iftari" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".felles"
        android:label="felles" >
    </activity>

    <!-- <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".AlarmService" /> -->
    <service android:name=".MyAlarmService" >
    </service>
    <service android:name=".UpdateWidgetService" >
    </service>


    <!-- Broadcast Receiver that will process AppWidget updates -->

    <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastreceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        <data android:scheme="package"  />
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name=".wimWidget"
        android:label="@string/app_nameWid" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/hello_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".SehriActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sehri" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
    package com.wim.wimonandroid;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAlarmService extends Service {
    MediaPlayer player;
    String readString = new String("");
    String readAlarm = new String("");
    String readSpilt = new String("");
    String readForste = new String("");
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private   AlarmManager alarmManager;

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Log.v("tid", "MyAlarmService - onCreate()" );

    try {
        readFile(); //sjekker om Alarm er slått på eller ei

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        hent(); //setter neste alarm
    } catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
    if(readString.equals("2")  ){ 
    Log.v("tid", "MyAlarmService - onCreate - Kaller onDestroy()" );
    onDestroy() ; 
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
//Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onBind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onDestroy();

Log.v("tid", "MyAlarmService - onDestroy");
//writeFile(2);
}



public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.v("tid", "MyAlarmService - onStartCommand()");

        String forste = new String(""); 

        try {
            readFile(); // Sjekker om alarm er på eller ei.

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


    try {
        forste = readForste();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) ; //1300
        int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE); 

        Log.v("tid", "MyAlarmService - onStartCommand - readAlarm: " + 
 readAlarm);    


        AudioManager am = 
(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);


        switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
                Log.v("tid","Silent mode");
                break;
            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
                Log.v("tid","Vibrate mode");
                break;
            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
                Log.v("tid","Normal mode - onStart");

            //  if(Integer.parseInt(readAlarm.trim()) == 0){                
                if(readAlarm.equals("0")){              

                Log.i("tid","Normal mode - door - Minutter: " + minutter);
                            am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,

  am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),   
 AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
                            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.door);
                            player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
                            player.setVolume(1, 1);
                            player.start(); 
                            player.release();
                            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                                    public void run(){

                                    }
                                };

                                Handler h = new Handler();
                                h.postDelayed(r, 60000);

                                //alarmHjelp.restart();

                }
                //else if(Integer.parseInt(readAlarm.trim()) == 1){
                else if(readAlarm.equals("1")){
                    Log.i("tid","Normal mode - azaan");
                        am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),  
                        AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);

                        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.azan);
                        player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
                        player.setVolume(1, 1);
                        player.start(); 
                       player.release();
                        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                                public void run(){

                                }
                            };

                            Handler h = new Handler();
                            h.postDelayed(r, 60000);
                }

                break;
        }


        if(readAlarm.equals("0") || readAlarm.equals("1")){
            Log.i("tid","vibrasjon");
            Vibrator v = (Vibrator)      
         getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            v.vibrate(4000);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tid for bønn..." ,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      


        }

    }       
        try {
            hent(); //setter neste alarm
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//} // 2 er lydløs



        Log.v("tid","MyAlarmService - OnStartCommand - Start sticky");
        return START_STICKY;
}


public void hent() throws IOException{
    Log.v("tid", "MyAlarmService - hent()");

    int alarmH = 0;                                 
    int alarmM = 0;

    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = cal2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) ; 
    int minutes = cal2.get(Calendar.MINUTE);    

    try {
        checkBy = readCity();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String tider = new String("");

    Log.v("tid", "MyAlarmService - hent() - By: " + checkBy);

     //Setting alarm every second hour
    alarmH = alarmH + 2;


        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmService.class);

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,  0, myIntent, 0);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        if(nesteDag == 1)
            {
                 Log.v("tid",  "MyAlarmService - hent() - nestedag");
                cal.add( Calendar.DATE, 1 );
            }

        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmH);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmM);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 
 pendingIntent);
        Log.i("tid", "MyAlarmService - hent() - Neste alarm: " + alarmH + 
 ":" + alarmM);



 }
}

public void readFile() throws IOException{

    Log.v("tid", "MyAlarmService - readFile() - readAlarm: " + readAlarm);

        // open the file for reading
        InputStream instream = openFileInput("alarm.txt");

        InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

        while (( readAlarm = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.v("tid", "readAlarm: " + readAlarm);

            break;
        }
        instream.close();

        if(readAlarm == null){
            Log.v("tid", "MyAlarmService - readFile - readAlarm er NULL");
            readAlarm = "2";
            writeFile(2);
            Log.v("tid", "MyAlarmService - readFile - readAlarm (ny verdi): 
 " + readAlarm);

        }

 }  

  public void onBackPressed()  
    {  
            this.startActivity(new Intent(this,wimOnAndroid.class));

    }

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onUnbind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not working properly? Is the alarm set? Or is the timing wrong? Also I recommend only the relevant bits of code. It's really a pain to search the full code for bugs etc.

Comment: I have now reduced some code. Sorry for being messy.

Comment: The alarm is set but not invoking every time. I cant find the bug. But please see the method "hent() " where the alarm is set.  The way im setting the alarm, is it OK?

Comment: You mean your alarm is set but is not being rung? That's not possible! Or is it that the alarm itself is never set or is it not even being set?

Comment: What you are trying to do is set a repeating alarm right. Check this link https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#set   And let me know if it works.

Comment: Im trying to set one alarm at time. so when the first one is executed, the next alarm will be set.  It works fine on emulator, but on the device: ONLY the first alarm is executed. But i can see that the alarmsservice is still running. I'm checking your link now. But how will the alarm be set if i want it to execute 1200 and 1700 o clock if i want to use these code?                   alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, alarmIntent);